# Scala filter on future of boolean inside for comprehension

Tags: scala, future, scala-collections, for-comprehension

I am trying to validate future of sequence of items. My validate method also returns future of boolean. I was able to make it work but I am not sure I understand whats happening here myself.

So, I have a code that works and one that does not work. Anyone have any idea whats happening here?
Also how to make it work by chaining filter after the map so that its all in one place and don't have to use the assignment later?

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(Await.result(testMethod(), Duration.Inf))
}
def validationMethod(n: Int) = {
    Future { n % 2 == 0 }
}
```

Code that works:

```
def testMethod() = {
for {
  seqOfIntegers <- Future { List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) }
  numberToBooleanTupleSeq <- Future.sequence(seqOfIntegers.map {
    number =>
      validationMethod(number)
        .map(validtedBooleanTuple => (number, validtedBooleanTuple))
  })

  finalIntegerSeq = numberToBooleanTupleSeq.filter(_._2).map(_._1)
} yield {
  finalIntegerSeq
}
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
  def testMethod() = {
    for {
      seqOfIntegers <- Future { List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) }
      finalIntegerSeq <- Future.sequence(seqOfIntegers.map {
        number =>
          validationMethod(number)
            .map(validtedBooleanTuple => (number, validtedBooleanTuple))
            .filter(_._2)
            .map(_._1)
      })
    } yield {
      finalIntegerSeq
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the types.
On your second snippet, you are calling `filter` over a **Future**, which doesn't work as you expect. Since, it doesn't remove that element from the collection of futures, but rather returns a *failed* **Future** with a `NoSuchElementException`, which then makes all the code to fail with such exception.

BTW, here is a polished version of your working code which is a little bit more efficient and readable.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

def validationMethod(n: Int): Future[Boolean] =
  Future((n % 2) == 0)

def testMethod() =
  for {
    seqOfIntegers <- Future {
      List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    }

    validated <- Future.traverse(seqOfIntegers) { number =>
      validationMethod(number).map { boolean =>
        number -> boolean
      }
    } 

    result = validated.collect {
      case (n, true) => n
    }
  } yield result
```